# How does cloning a visa work

Tags: seven-the-days-long-gone

After playing Seven: The Days Long Gone for a few hours, I just discovered that there is the option to clone a visa from knocked out NPCs. Here, I am missing visa 5, and the NPC near me has it:

[image: NPC With Desired Visa]

I knock him out and use the "Clone Visa" option on him:

[image: Clone visa menu option]

I now appear to have visa 5, it shows up in yellow on my visa display:

[image: Visa successfully cloned]

About 2 seconds later it goes away and I'm back to not having visa 5. Am I doing something wrong? Does visa cloning not do what I expect? (I expect it to give me the visa, or something along those lines) Does visa cloning do something at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visa clone duration was previously quite short. In patch 1.0.7 it was changed to last for 10 minutes.